# My transaction is showing validate signature error

Tags: transactions

This is what the transaction is showing. What could be the cause?[image]

Comment: Which blockchain are you using? What wallet are you using? The address format doesn't look like the ethereum format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.